# HTML Email Internal link not working in Outlook and Gmail mobile app

Tags: html, email, outlook

It's painful while designing HTML email. I have added back to top link in my HTML email in following format.

```
<!-- Define top -->
<a name="top" id="top"></a>

<!-- Display Link to top -->
<a href="#top">Back to Top</a>
```

This works in outlook desktop app, but not working on mobile. Is there any way of make it working.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine in Outlook 2013, IOS and Gmail. I ran a test just to see what might happen and posted the code:

- https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/n9j2zjzq/

Going down the email:

`<a href="#C4">Jump to Chapter 4</a>
<a name="C4"></a>`

Going to the top:

`<a name="top"></a>
<a href="#top">Jump to Top</a>`

There's a few caveats working with internal hrefs.

First off, you need email document length for the page to move. In Gmail, it would not work until I made the window smaller.

You need enough document room below the `a name` for at the bottom to work. If the `a name` is on the bottom line, unless you add space below it, the page will not move.

The `<a name>` and the `<a href>` are case sensitive. If they don't match, it will never work.

Comment: This method does not work on any of the latest Outlook, Gmail and iOS Mail mobile apps. These methods only work on desktop version and in browser.

Comment: Is there any way of make it working on mobile apps or right now it's impossible.

Comment: @ShankarPrakashG I tested this before I posted. I suggest you do the same.

Comment: I have also tested, it's not working on any of mobile apps(Outlook, Gmail, iOS Mail) and I'm trying to solve this issue only.

Comment: @ShankarPrakashG Try the JSFiddle I posted earlier and see what happens when you test it.

Comment: Confirm Shankar - this doesn't work in Outlook 2016 & Gmail web version. Still can't find a solution.